# Copy and replace text via SH file

Tags: linux, unix, sh

I have literally no experience in unix and shell scripting but I need to populate 100 similar folders with the same files with only a difference in a specific text.

For example, I have the "dataxxx" folder which has 2 files. I need to copy that folder to data1, data2, data3, ..., data100. The files inside them are simple text files where in I need to replace all instances of dataxxx to the folder name `(data1, data2, data3, ..., data100)`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make a best effort attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a first sample of how to accomplish your task. Note that this example easily generalizes to any symbol, not just numbers {1..100}, and illustrates many useful shell idioms.

First, create a file with 100 entries, one on each line *(you could use an editor, or the file could be the result of a database query, etc)*.

```
cat > list <<HERE
1
2
3
...
100
HERE
```

(The above shows how to create a file without an editor, and can be placed into a script).

Or you could use a script to count *(see David Rankin's answer)*, etc.

```
for i in $(seq 1 100); do echo $i; done > list
```

Then a short script to perform the copy, etc for each element of list,

```
for number in `cat list`; do
    symbol="data$number"; #construct string from variable, constant text
    mkdir $symbol; #make the directory you need
    cp -p dataxxx/* $symbol/; #copy your template files
    #now you need to edit each file in directory $symbol/
    for file in `ls $symbol`; do
        sed -i ‘s/dataxxx/$symbol/g’ $file; #rewrite your template files
    done
done
```

Use sed to do the changes - to change all instances of a word in a file the command is

```
sed -i ‘s/original_word/new_word/g’ file.txt
```

the “g” at the end tells sed to perform the action globally.

Comment: There's no need to create a file; there are several ways to generate a sequence of numbers, depending on which shell is in use.

Comment: Agreed, but go meta, and understand that you have someone new to the site that needs a bit of help and guidance, and this shows them a bit more about how to use sh. This solution fully generalizes to any symbols, not just numbers.

Comment: Don't loop over backticks. The preferred idiom is `while read -r stuff; do ...; done <file`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the `dataxxx` is located in your desktop. Now you can do this simply by only two commands .

```
mkdir ~/Desktop/data{1..100}

for d in ~/Desktop/data{1..100}; do
  cp -a ~/Desktop/dataxx "$d"
done
```

save it to a file  named copy.sh and run it by `bash copy.sh`( checked for `ubuntu` .Different linux distribution can different procedure to run a `sh` file see it .) 
It works for me . Reply if it works. for more see using terminal `man cp`

Comment: At first you have to try and then question. As you are new, i have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another that makes use of `seq` and contains error-checking/validation of input and directory creation. You can choose whether or not to remove the original `dataxxx` directory at the end by uncommenting the `rm` command:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ -d "$1" ] || {  ## validate source directory given
    printf "error: insufficient input, usage: %s srcdir\n" "${0//*\//}"
    exit 1
}

for i in $(seq 1 100); do
    newdir="data$i"             ## form new directory name from seq val
    mkdir -p "$newdir" || {     ## create new directory data1 - data100
        printf "error: directory creation failed '%s'\n" "$newdir"
        exit 1
    }
    cp -a "$1"/* "$newdir"      ## copy contents of dataxxx to $newdir
done

# rm -f "$1"   ## optionally remove original source directory
```